# public interface ITMark<E extends Comparable<E>>

Tags: java, class, interface, comparable, implements

now i want to implement this interface with the class. 
so how should i do it?

```
public class TMark<E> implements ITMark{}
```

is this the way but throwing errors

I am getting the following:

```
ITMark is a raw type. References to generate type ITMark<E> should be parametrized
```

I am implementing this code in Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
public class TMark<SomeComparableClass> implements ITMark<SomeComparableClass> {
    // implement the methods of ITMark for type SomeComparableClass
}
```

You must specify *which* Comparable class you are implementing for this class. FYI, most common java types (eg Integer, String, Date, etc) are Comparable.

Answer (score 0):

`ITMark` is a raw type because it has no declared generic parameters.

If you declared `TMark` as `TMark<E extends Comparable<E>> implements ITMark<E>`, it would not longer be a raw type because you declared its generic parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You left out the generic parameter, that is, the part that goes in the angle brackets.  You need something like:

```
public class TMark <E extends Comparable <E> implements ITMark<E>
{
    ...
}
```

For a particular generic type you put a suitable 'Comparable' type inside the angle brackets, something like:

```
public class IntegerTMark extends TMark <Integer>
{
    ...
}
```

For a good introduction to generics, read the Java tutorials, the free chapter from Joshua Bloch's *Effective Java* at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/generics.pdf and the many articles about generics at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/.